# How to format hidden rows/columns in a table?

Tags: excel, vba, range, filtering

The following code works to highlight target row and column:

```
Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub 
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Clear the color of all cells
    Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    With Target
        'Highlight row and column of the selected cell
        .EntireColumn.Interior.ColorIndex = 24
        .EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    End With

End Sub
```

However, if the target is in a table and I apply a filter, the rows/ columns that were highlighted before the filter was applied remain highlighted.  In other words, any rows/ columns that are hidden remain highlighted after the target is changed (another cell is selected) or filter is changed.

**Question**: how to change formatting i.e. clear the color of any hidden rows/columns after a filter is applied and the target is changed?

I was thinking of the looping through each row/ column of the table `ListObjects(1)` and if it is hidden, then clearing the color `ColorIndex = 0`.

I came up with the code below but I keep getting an error

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the Hidden property of the Range class

```
Dim oList As ListObject
Dim oRow As ListRow

Set oList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
For Each oRow In oList.ListRows
    If oRow.Range.Hidden Then
        oRow.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    
    Else
        oRow.Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    End If
    
Next oRow
```

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Hidden` only works with an entire row or column. The error is due to `ListRow.Range` not referencing an entire row. Change to:

```
If oRow.Range.EntireRow.Hidden Then
```